# Jquery auto scroll after scrolling 30%

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a serious problem:
I have a bootstrap page with 5 full-page div and I need auto-scrolling:

If you scrolled down on first div 30%, auto scroll to the second div. If you scrolled down on second div 30%, scroll down to third div, etc.

I can't find a good method and I am not good at jquery. :/
This code is okay, but I can't scroll after the autoscroll. :D

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#A2").offset().top
}, 100);}});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of ways to do this. I have attached two ways. Since you didnt post any css or markup. I am just assuming the following barebones

```
<div class="scene">
<div class="first blade"> <h2>FIRST</h2></div>
  <div class="second blade"><h2>SECOND</h2></div>
  <div class="third blade"><h2>THIRD</h2></div>
</div>

.blade {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Approach 1 jquery

```
$('.blade').each(function(){
  $(this).data('cutOff', $(this).height() * 0.3 + $(this).offset().top)
 });

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
   var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();

   $('.blade').each(function(index){
     if(scrollVal>=$(this).data('cutOff')) {
            if($(this).data('cutOffReached') == false && (index <=$('.blade').length -1)){
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
            }, 100);
            $(this).data('cutOffReached', true);        
          }        
     }else {
          $(this).data('cutOffReached', false)
     } 
    });
});
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fjcnnt6t/

Approach 2 scrollmagic like @Emmanuel mentioned. My goto library which gives more control.

```
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(); 

 $('.blade').each(function(index){ 
   var scene;
   var blade = $(this);
   var offset = $(this).height() * 0.3;
   scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene( {triggerElement: this, triggerHook:0, duration: $(this).height() - offset, offset: offset} );

   scene.on('enter', function(e){
      if((index <  $('.blade').length - 1) && e.scrollDirection == "FORWARD") {
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: blade.next().offset().top
          }, 100);
      }
   });
   scene.on('leave', function(){

   });
   scene.addTo(controller);
    // To get a clear perspective of the trigger points uncomment this
   //scene.addIndicators({name: 'scene '+index})
 });
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/og1s8uga/

Note:
1. The UX of this is very questionable.
2. Suggest you to use scrollmagic as it gives a granular control.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either:

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage
or http://scrollmagic.io/

both could achieve this, just depends if you want to use plugins or not